# What is the best driver for mysql to connect?

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc-sql-server-driver

I think quesiton is clear.
I'm programming with [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-sharp) and using [MySQLDriverCS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqldrivercs/) to connect [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).
But I'm having issues about speed.
Which drivers are you using to connect MySQL?
MySQLDriverCS is the best solution?
Please make some suggestions for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My plain ODBC connection worked against a 32-bit CentOS MySQL server, but C# could not get to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:
[mysql connector/net](http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html)

or you can use [OleDB](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Database/Database-Programming-in-C-Sharp-with-MySQL-Using-OleDB/)

Comment: I've been downloading the wrong drivers. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the official [MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

Comment: Ditto. I've been downloading the wrong drivers. Thanks for the answer